# How to fix Tkinter dead frezzing or crashing because of huge data?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a program to display one single image (.png extension) at once but giving a button to the user to change the picture.

What I have done is:

1. Reading the Image from my directory with help of Pillow module
2. Appended it to a list
3. With a button I increase or decrease the index of the list.

(*Note I have to read 600 images approx.*)

Here's the code:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import threading,time
#Define the tkinter instance
x=0
win= Tk()
dir_path= os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(dir_path)
l1=[]
#Define the size of the tkinter frame
win.geometry("700x400")
def start():
    threading.Thread(target=bg).start()
    win.after(5000,threading.Thread(target=fg).start())
#Define the function to start the thread
def bg():
    print("bg")
    for i in range(1,604):
        a=Image.open(f"{dir_path}\\{i}.png")
        a=a.resize((500,700), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        b=ImageTk.PhotoImage(a)
        l1.append(b)
        print(b)
        print(len(l1))
def fg():
    def add():
        global x
        x+=1
        img2=l1[x]
        d.configure(image=img2)
        d.image = img2
        d.update()
    global d
    d=Label(win,image=l1[x])
    d.pack()
    Button(win,text="add",command=add).place(x=0,y=0)
label= Label(win)
label.pack(pady=20)
#Create button
b1= Button(win,text= "Start", command=start)

b1.pack(pady=20)

win.mainloop()
```

But the problem is that the Tkinter gets dead freeze and laggy to an extent that the GUI is not operable.

So my question is,

*How to fix Tkinter dead Frezzes and if there is any way to read the images as fast as possible?*

Comment: `win.after(5000,threading.Thread(target=fg).start())` should be `win.after(5000,threading.Thread(target=fg).start)` instead.  Also I cannot reproduce the freeze issue.  It is better to disable/remove `Start` button after clicking it.

Comment: oh ok thx for the response, is there an alternative if i want to display images in tkinter with out frezze

Comment: I have already said *"I cannot reproduce the freeze issue"* in my comment.

Comment: oh ye sorry havnt seen that

Comment: You shouldn't call `tkinter` functions from other threads. It can cause `tkinter` to crash without even giving you a traceback.

Comment: Is this some kind of [slideshow](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c)?

Comment: @8349697 , ye you guessed it right!

Comment: @TheLizzard , you meant not to call Labels ect right?

Comment: @8349697 , i tried the code in slideshow, but it tkinter lagged, ig its cuz i am reading around 600 images with  total size 150 mb. But the selenium pretty worked for me.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The freezes of Tkinter depends on reading speed of the interpreter, because:

- continuously reading and Showing the pictures are a huge job for Python.
- reading images using opencv or any other image processing module wont help as reading part can become faster, but showing the image in tkinter is done using python only, so rapid changes in `Label` will cause tkinter to crash.

Solution:

- Switch to a different compiler based language for example c++.
- this solution is specifically for a image slideshow,

The solution is to use selenium with python. You can specify the image location in  `driver.get(image_path)` and it will open the image for you, and if you want to change the image with a button, then just rename all your images with the numbers and make a button to add +1 to the index.